# EF6 Code First many-to-many without collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

So I have the following model in EF:

```
public class User: IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Email { get; protected set; }
    internal User()
    {
    }

    public User(Guid id, string email)
    {
        Id = id;
        Email = email;
    }
}

public class Tenant : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    internal Tenant() { }

    public Tenant(Guid id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I would like to have a many-to-many relationship between these entities without having collections in them.

I have tried creating a join entity like:

```
public class TenantUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    internal TenantUser ()
    {
    }

    public TenantUser(Tenant tenant, User user )
    {
        this.Tenant = tenant;
        this.User = user;
    }
}
```

With the following setup:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TenantUser>()
   .HasRequired<Tenant>(m => m.Tenant)
   .WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<TenantUser>()
   .HasRequired<User>(m => m.User)
   .WithMany();
```

When I save TenantUser objects, the database is populated with the correct foreign keys. When I query the TenantUser DbSet for all rows, it returns all rows, but I'm only getting the Id value populated, Tenant and User are both null.

I tried adding TenantId and UserId fields to TenantUser and then doing HasForeignKey for those fields, but it made no difference; TenantId and UserId were populated on query, but Tenant and User were still null.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. Any thoughts would be great :)

Comment: Im a little unsure what relationship you are trying to create here? Can you describe the relationship you are after in words or perhaps if its easier post a DB digram of the relationship.

Comment: The problem is probably just that you're not including the `User` and `Tenant` when you query the table (rather than in the config itself). I'm not sure that can be configured, but try querying with `ctx.TenantUsers.Include(tu => tu.Tenant).Include(tu => tu.User)`.

Comment: This is rather unclear.  What do you mean you want a many to many without collections? What other way is there to reference an object which has a relationship to many other items than to have the other items in a collection of some sort?

Comment: sorry if that was unclear, but I mean without collection properties in the Tenant or User entities. Basically how a normal SQL join table would work. The most typical case here would be that I would query TenantUser by User.Id and select Tenant into an IEnumerable. I feel like sriban's answer is a winner but I'm not in a position to test it for a little while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want many-to-many then remove the configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TenantUser>()
.HasRequired<Tenant>(m => m.Tenant)
.WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<TenantUser>()
.HasRequired<User>(m => m.User)
.WithMany();
```

Why? Because EF use agreements:

```
public class User: IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
}

public class Tenant : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
}

public class TenantUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

This is fluent many-to-many.

When you make a query, use:

```
public class UnitOfWork : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<TenantUser> TenantUsers { get; set; }
}

context.TenantUsers.Include(e => e.Tenant).Include(e => e.User);
```

Then EF Include them in the mapping

Comment: It looks like that works, thanks. Quick question, though. I don't see an Include method that takes a lambda expression, I'm only seeing an Include that takes a string. If I do Include("Tenant").Include("User") it works. Is that what you meant, or is there an extension method that would allow me to use an expression instead? (preferable)

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in `System.Data.Entity`. Thanks!